# Data Table to Livecharts

Tags: c#, sql

I am using Live charts library in my Application to generate a Line graph. The way it works is like this;

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
{
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Series 1",
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,4 }
    },
    new LineSeries
    {
        Title = "Series 2",
        Values = new ChartValues<double> { 6, 7, 3, 4 ,6 },
        PointGeometry = null
    },

};

Labels = new[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"};
YFormatter = value => value.ToString("C");
```

I am trying to use a datatable to get values for the X and Y axis.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DateTime date_1 = DateTime.Today;
DateTime date_2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);
dt = dbaction_rbt.RBT_Data(date_1, date_2);

var x_axis = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["To_Date"].ToString()).ToArray();
var y_axis= dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["Order"]).ToArray();
```

I am having some difficulties with passing x_axis(strings) and y_axis(integers) data to graph values.

```
dbaction_rbt.RBT_Data(date_1, date_2)
```

is coming from a stored proc;

I tried to convert them to array but no luck.
I am still new to programming world, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the y-axis into an integer convert it into double as below because the **Values** property of **LineSeries** expects a collection of double values.

```
var y_axis = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => Convert.ToDouble(row["Order"])).ToArray();
```